# paypal ios sdk non-US release

Tags: ios, sdk, paypal

I'm a Non-US developer building an iOS app that will also run outside US.

I've searched for a while about when will the iOS SDK be available outside US but couldn't find anything.

I´d be glad if someone knows when it will be released and where can I follow the released date.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nobody except PayPal knows exactly when the SDK will be released.

If you want to work with PayPal, it looks like you don't have any options:  you have to keep using MPL.

According to this in the first couple paragraphs of https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/mobile/ios-integration-guide/

> PayPal is replacing the Mobile Payments Libraries (MPL) with the
>   PayPal iOS SDK. The PayPal iOS SDK is currently available in the US,
>   with more country support coming soon. US developers should upgrade
>   now for more features and a better mobile experience. Non-US
>   developers, you can continue to use MPL for the time being.

I would suggest e-mailing or contacting PayPal to tell them to allow worldwide developers in on the fun of the new iOS SDK a.s.a.p.

Or that you'll be considering making a permanent to a different payment processor (e.g. [Dwolla](http://blog.dwolla.com/introducing-our-new-mobile-sdks/) or [who knows what else](http://lifehacker.com/5821634/why-you-should-ditch-paypal-and-use-these-other-services-to-send-people-money)?).

Comment: Are the any news about this??